# retrieving data from multiples tables

Tags: php, mysql

hello every one please help me regarding how to make a good query to fetch the data from three table. I am making a database in which there will be users , employee and services which will provided to users via employee so i have set that table name as task. Now i can add the task by fetching the data from different table , the thing right now i want to do is show the entire record by fetching all the client data and services available to him and and who will be going to perform that services . so how can i put the query on the task table to fetch the data from the other table. Thanks

```
**task table** 
task_id user_id  employee_id    service_id  starttime   endtime date
```

by using this table i have to fetch data from other three table  by using

user_id employee_id service_id

```
employee table
employee_id pno name    age pic_path

user table
user_id pno name    age pic_path


service table
service_id  name    description
```

Comment: Read up on INNER JOIN in MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    e.name AS employee_name,
    u.name AS user_name,
    s.name AS service_name, s.description
FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN employees AS e ON e.employee_id = t.employee_id
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = t.user_id
INNER JOIN services AS s ON s.service_id = t.service_id
```